# TryParse for numbers in C#?

Tags: c#, tryparse

So I want to use a TryParse method, but so far I can do it only with integer or double value. However, I want to check if the value is a number, and if it's not (if it is a string for instance) to get a false value. Something like IsDigit() is Java.

```
static void Main()
    {
        int number;
        Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
        bool result = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number); 
        if (result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The input number is an integer.");
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The input number is not an integer.");
        }
    }
```

So I want to do that, but instead of checking for an integer value, I'd like to check for a numerical value. So if anybody can tell me what method I can use I'd be very happy.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "number value" and why is it not satisfied with TryParse for ints or doubles?

Comment: I would also like to know what Boyan Kushlev considers the difference between "a numerical value" and double. What string would represent a number but not be parsable as double?

Comment: any non numeric number will return false, what is problem here ??

Comment: @Tobberoth 1e123456789 is a number, but it can't be parsed as a double.

Comment: @DavidArno Double.TryParse() handles scientific notation just fine...

Comment: @Tobberoth Try it for yourself. `double.TryParse("1e123456789", out d)` will return false as it is too large a number to fit in a double. The accepted answer is the wrong answer to the question.

Comment: @DavidArno True, but you can use Double.Parse() instead and handle the overflow exception in case you're expecting to run into massive numbers.

Comment: @Tobberoth You could do that, but that would be ugly code compared with a neat regex test as per my answer.

Comment: @DavidArno I agree, if you don't need the number as a numerical variable, regexp seems like the better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `double`:

```
double number;
bool result = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number);
```

This will parse *any* real number.

Comment: No it will not. Thee are plenty of real numbers way outside its ability to parse.

Comment: Try `double.TryParse("1e123456789", out number)`. It will return false.

Comment: Yeah, I got your point, the answer is correct as it corresponds to his definition of numerical value.

Comment: @Ofiris : How can i make it to return false when 1.2.3 is parsed.

Answer (score 2):

TryParse for decimal or double types is your limit for built in methods. If you want more than that, you'd have to parse the string yourself. The can be quite easily done using a regex, such as

```
^-?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?$
```

Comment: Assume the input is `e3`, to which `double` would you convert it and how ? how would you translate the input to a variable you can work with ? (any input)

Comment: @Ofiris "e3" would not match the regex as the `[0-9]+` part requires at least one digit.

Comment: `var regex = new Regex(@"-?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*([Ee][+-]?[0-9]+)?");
var m = regex.Match("5.5.5"); // .Success == True`

Comment: @Ofiris Well spotted. Updated now to only match the whole string, not just part of it.

Comment: Ok, +1 then, I think its better to keep it simple this time, but your answer is correct as well.

Answer (score 1):

For a single character, there's [`Char.IsDigit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t641e58%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In that case you may want to look at `Console.ReadKey()` instead of reading a whole line. By the way, `Char.IsDigit()` also matches digits [from other cultures](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/09/86555.aspx).

For multiple characters you'll need to think about what you want to accept. decimals, exponents, negative numbers, or just multiple digit characters?

Answer (score 1):

```
bool result = double.TryParse(mystring, out num);
```

The `double.TryParse` also works on integers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a regular expression

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^-*[0-9\.]+$");
var m = regex.Match(text);
if (m.Sucess)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The input number is an integer.");
    }

    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The input number is not an integer.");
    }
```

You can also allow separators by including them in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
static bool enteredNumber()
{
    int intValue;
    double doubleValue;
    Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    return Int32.TryParse(input, out intValue) ? true : double.TryParse(input, out doubleValue);
}
```

Comment: the `Int32.TryParse(input, out intValue)` is not needed as it is covered by the latter.